# Form element with type = value odd behaviour

Tags: 7, forms

I have 2 forms on the site, each of them has an array, that I want to store inside the form to use in `form_submit` function:

```
$form['store'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $fields
);
```

But in one `form_submit` function this works:

```
$fields = $form_state['values']['store'];
unset($form_state['values']['store']);
```

In another one it doesn't work, giving an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: store in scores_search_form_submit

While this code works:

```
$fields = $form_state["complete form"]["store"]["#value"];
unset($form_state["complete form"]["store"]);
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: If the code works in one submit handler is stands to reason it should work in any other, unless there's something else in the form that's conflicting. Could you post the code for both forms and submit handlers?

Comment: Ok, I'll take a careful comparison of the code and will try to find out the issue myself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use form properties:

```
$form['#mystore'] = $fields;
```

The form properties are not sent to the client, but are available in the submit hander. For example, core use `$form['#node']`, `$form['#user']`, etc.

Updated:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html#val

> Note that as of Drupal 6, you can also simply store arbitrary
>   variables in $form['#foo'] instead, as long as '#foo' does not
>   conflict with any other internal property of the Form API.

Updated 2:

Your problem may be related to this issue: http://drupal.org/node/1381830

Answer (score -1):

Try to store the values within `$form_state`

```
$form_state['storage']['store'] = $fields;
```

And access the same within your submit functions.

```
$fields = $form_state['storage']['store'];
```